# Unable to find tutorials for accessing device specific features in firefox os

Tags: firefox-os

I want to develop an application for firefox os. But i'm unable to find any tutorial for accessing its device specific features. Pls suggest me a good tutorial for it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the [MDN](http://developers.mozilla.org) you will find documentation about WebAPIs. WebAPIs are the way to access device's capabilities in app code.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you.. but, many APIs are authorized only for certified apps. how can i get proper certification for my app.. can u pls tell me how to proceed?

Comment: The certified level WebAPIs is intended for stock/system apps. Thus, while some of those APIs are going to be available for third party apps in the future, right now you can only use WebAPIs with at most the privileged level. You can find further reference at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/App_permissions